# Visual Studio Online - Error TFS 22501 with XAML Build Definition 2

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently, we are using TFS 2012 and we have a heavily customized build process as described below.
1. Build the source
2. Run an EXE as console to host WCF services
3. Restore databases on local sql server
4. Run functional test
5. delete databases
6. close the exe started in step 2.
7. Create an Installable exe using WiX ( Wix with custom bootstratpper)
8. Update version number file to TFS

Now we want to move to Visual Studio online from onpremise. Trying to setup a build process with Private Build agent. I have created an VM , installed and registerd agent. I do see agent name back in website.
When I go back to Visual studio and  try to create new xaml build definition I am getting below error.

**TFS22501: Creating a build definition requires a build controller be defined for this team project collection.    There may not be any controllers configured or you may not have permissions to view them. contact your team foundation server administrator.**

can somebody please help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAML build, you have to use the old-style XAML build controller/agent. The VSTS agent is for the new build system.

I would strongly recommend migrating your builds to the new build system as part of your migration to VS Team Services, as the XAML build system is effectively dead.

Comment: How do i create old style  controller and agents for VSTS (VS online)? Can you give me some steps or reference?

Comment: Install the XAML build controller from TFS installation media.